# searchkit - RefinementListFilter Checkboxes Not Persisting State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, searchkit

I have a question about the RefinementListFilter in searchkit. I have a few filters that are booleans, for example: `{field: 'hasChildren': {'1' : 'Yes', '0': 'No'}}` to give an example of the translation for that field. For some reason, I can persist the correct selected filters after a page refresh in the url, and in the SelectedFilters/GroupSelectedFilters, but the actual checkboxes in the RefinementListFilter are not checked after you refresh the view. An example of the url query string: `&hasChildren[0]=1`, where `hasChildren` is true. Do you have an idea why the checkboxes arent reflecting the state of the query correctly? I can provide more info if you need. Thank you!

PS: My ES mappings has that `hasChildren` field as a type boolean if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a `boolean` field but it's working perfectly with `RefinementListFilter`. The value is `true` or `false`. I just need to add

```
Boolean(fields={'raw': Keyword()})
```

on my mapping, then call it on field part `RefinementListFilter` as `item.raw`.

I'm a little confused by the question.. Hope this solves your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Ah ok, we don't have the .raw keyword in our mappings. It's definitely worth checking out! I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!